# iOS UILocalNotification - Is it possible catch the Local Notification when the Application opens without do that on Delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, cordova-plugins

Is there way to handle the Local Notifications when the user click on the notification without being in the Delegate? I want catch a deep link from a Local Notification but without do it in Delegate but i don't know if this is possible.

The idea is do this as a Cordova Plugin.

Comment: The only notification an app receives of a local notification being tapped by the user is the delegate method of `UIApplicationDelegate` (i.e. AppDelegate).

Comment: ok, so I need always to do override of methods in Delegate, right? Can't I catch the event to open the app from a Local Notification in other way? Thanks.